# Is になど used here correctly?

Tags: grammar, meaning, translation

So in th song advise by ARARE a line that reads the next

> 天国になどとうに行けないけど この音楽なら聴ける

Is など here used after に for lyrical  purposes or does it have another use since it does not make sense to me !

Answer (score 2):

など here is used to make light of 天国(に). This など is a less colloquial variation of なんか/なんて.

- [JLPT N3 Grammar: なんか / なんて / など](https://jlptsensei.com/learn-japanese-grammar/%E3%81%AA%E3%82%93%E3%81%8B-nanka-%E3%81%AA%E3%82%93%E3%81%A8-nante-%E3%81%AA%E3%81%A9-nado-meaning/)

This とうに is [this](https://jisho.org/word/%E7%96%BE%E3%81%86%E3%81%AB). So:

- 天国に行けない
  I cannot go to heaven
- 天国に**など**行けない
  I cannot go to (something like) heaven
- 天国になど**とうに**行けない
  I've long lost my right/chance to go to heaven

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I am asking about why など is not used directly  after 天国  rather after に ?

Comment: @user50156 Words like だけ, なんか and など can go either before or after another particle (e.g., 金でなんか買えない = 金なんかで買えない; 君だけに言う = 君にだけ言う), but when など comes directly after a noun, it may tend to mean "et cetera", so I think 天国になど is better in this context. Words like すら, まで (meaning "even") comes only after the other particle.